# How to plot dataframe values on x-axis and indices on y-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, dataframe

I have two problems, but solving either of them neglects the need to solve the other.

I have a dataframe with temperature-values from e.g. 6 places in several (e.g. 3) heights. The heights are locked and are thus the indices of the dataframe. Example (does not match the figures):

```
  place1 place2 place3 place4 place5 place6
1     12     10      9     13     10      4
2     18     15     13     14      8      8
3     21      9     16     15     11     12
```

I want to plot the temperatures for every place as a function of the height, HOWEVER!, **I want the height (the indices) to be along the Y-AXIS instead of the x-axis**. So instead of having the graphs running 'from left to right', I want the to run 'from down to up'.

If I just [Plot a DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCipN.png) it looks somewhat like this: The indices (heights) run along the X-axis and not the Y-axis.
- NOTE that values don't match table!!

```
ax.plot(data)
```

It does NOT work to transpose the array: it is still the values along the Y-axis that are flexible to locked X-values.

I want it to [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFI5x.png) with the variable temperature along the X-axis and the locked heights along the Y-axis. (PLEASE DON'T BOTHER the different dataset; the point is that the graphs are 'vertical' instead of horizontal):

```
ax.errorbar(temp, H, xerr=tempError, ecolor='gray')
```

The latter was made from plotting simple python lists and that work for me. However, my dataset is big so utilizing DataFrames would be nice AND, most importantly, I want to use the `fill_betweenx` to show the `std` instead of the errorbars currently presented as in the figure.

So I'm actually looking for an answer to any of these two questions:

1. How do i flip the plot from a DataFrame (i.e. not transpose the df, but make the axis swap)?
2. or, how do I utilize the `fill_betweenx` without using DataFrames?

Comment: What does ```NOTE that values don't match table!!``` mean.

Answer (score 3):

Use pyplot.plot and structure the x's and y's the way you want.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df.place1, df.index, df.place2, df.index, df.place3, df.index,
         df.place4, df.index, df.place5, df.index, df.place6, df.index)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Or a little more general:

```
for name, series in df.iteritems():
    plt.plot(series, df.index)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is suggestion for question no. 1

```
plt.plot(data, range(number_of_heights))
```

in your example number_of_heights is 3

Comment: looking briefly at the question, you need an iteration and it's not in your answer?